# Sorting dictionary by values in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary with key as words and values as ints.

Is it possible to sort the dictionary by values?

I want to be able to take the top 10 most occurring words in my dictionary. The values represent the word counts and the keys represent the word.

```
counter = 9
for a,b in sorted(dict_.iteritems()):
        if counter > 0:
            print str(a),str(b)+"\n"
            counter-=1
```

This is what i have so far but it is only printing off the first 10 items in the dictionary. How would I print off the top 10 most frequent items? (ie The values with the highest int as the value?)

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries are unordered, but you can convert it to a list of tuples using `items()` and pass an appropriate comparison function to `sort`'s `key` parameter.

[`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) has an analogous key parameter. You'd want to sort by `lambda item: item[1]` to get the value out of `items()` and `iteritems()`. Then you can just slice off the first N items.

So...

```
for a, b in sorted(dict_.iteritems(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)[:10]:
    print a, b
```

Comment: Isn't this now 
`for a, b in sorted(dict_.iteritems(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)[:10]:`

Comment: @MichaelTomkins: It is! 2011 me must have missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sorted(dict_.iteritems(), key=lambda item: -item[1])`.

Comment: @khachik: It's to reverse the list.

Comment: @nmichaels: Then it should be mapped back by `lambda x: (x[0], -x[1])`? Why not `sorted(..., key=..., reverse=True)`?

Comment: Negating the key and adding reverse=True have equivalent effects.  There is no effect on the sorted items that are returned, only their order.  I used the negative key because it's my personal stylistic preference.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sorted(dict_.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

or

```
import operator
sorted(.... key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

to sort based on element values. You can use the `reverse=True` argument to invert the order of the results (default oder is ascending values) and slice notation (`results[:10]`) to iterate only the first 10 elements. You can also omit the reverse flag and use `[-10:]` to get the top 10.

Comment: Ahhh, I love me some `operator`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort dicts at all. They're unordered, i.e. the order is undefined and completely meaningless (for you).

However, you can sort `.iteritems()` with `key=operator.itemgetter(1)` (other answers negate the value, but you can just use the slice `[-10:]` to get the last 10 items). Or, in this particular case, just use `collections.Counter`, which comes with a `.most_common(n)` method.

Comment: dicts are unordered is obvious but the question is that is it possible to sort it on values.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you should sort it using the `key` argument. `key` must be a function that takes an element as input and returns another that should be sortable and it will sort the whole elements using this key. And take the last 10 elements (it is sorted in ascending order). In your case you will need to do something like this:

```
for a,b in sorted(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), dict_.iteritems())[-10:]:
    print str(a), str(b)
```